# ajax search deep linking with hashbag problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, hash, deep-linking

I'm trying to build an ajax search with deep linking and so far my codes looks as it follows. This area is quite new for me and I'm trying to understand the basics. The following should pick up values from UI slider and pass it to search method which would execute an ajax call. On the other hand on page load I would like to check if there is hash tag and call the before mentioned method. This one works fine, but on mouse up event can't get the search method to get called

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.layout-slider').on('mouseup', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        facet = $(this).find(':input').attr('name')
        values = $(this).find(':input').val();
        console.log(facet);
        console.log(values);
        var url = facet + "=" + values;
        window.location.hash = "#!" + url;

    });

});

  if (window.location.hash) {
        search();
    }


function search(){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
        console.log(hash);
        $.post("site/ajax", function() {
            console.log("Load was performed.");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling your search function from your mouse up event. You are just appending a hashtag to the Url. Just add search() to the end of it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.layout-slider').on('mouseup', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        facet = $(this).find(':input').attr('name')
        values = $(this).find(':input').val();
        console.log(facet);
        console.log(values);
        var url = facet + "=" + values;
        window.location.hash = "#!" + url;
        search();
    });
});
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but from quickly looking I would personally go about it slightly different by passing an argument to the search function, such as.

```
function search(value){
   $.post("site/ajax", function() {
      console.log(value);
   });
}

$(function(){
   if (window.location.hash) {
      search(window.location.hash.substring(1));
   }
   $('.layout-slider').on('mouseup', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var facet = $(this).find(':input').attr('name')
      var values = $(this).find(':input').val();
      var url = "#!" + facet + "=" + values;
      search(url);
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks I see now this should work. Just to ask is this an approach to make ajax deep linking or am I on wrong track?

Comment: @fefe TBH I know what deep linking is, I'v just never heard it called that before. Ignore my recent edit then, if you want to be able to record the users actions on a single page through hashtags (so the nav buttons can be used) then yes you'll need to append the hashtags. Looks fine to me.